# Remove index.php from the url when using the CakePHP pretty URLs

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, routes

I want to remove the index.php from the url: http://mywebsite/index.php/.
I m using CakePHP pretty URLs, I removed all the .htaccess files:

```
/.htaccess
/app/.htaccess
/app/webroot/.htaccess
```

and uncommented the App.baseUrl on the core.php.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why would you remove those files? That's exactly the opposite of what you need to do. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#url-rewriting**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. it's because it was the only way that works for me. I've tried before to  work with mod_rewrite but it doesn't work (only the home page worked). I will try again maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: something like index.php is not how it should work out of the box. You should not need changes of htaccess. Check how to configure routes here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this. i have been using this for my codeigniter and i think this will work for you too.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

oh you dont want to use htaccess? . i misundestood your question.

Comment: I've tried to use the.htaccess files. And only the homepage works, the other pages had a 500 server error. '.htaccess

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

app/.htaccess

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]

webroot/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

Comment: because inside your index.php will be the one to route properly your url. but `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L,NC]` will catch your url to handle by your index.php nd something is not working in your code maybe.